# Adding VC++ to Eclipse toolchain

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eclipse, ide

I want to write a program to link with binaries already created with VC++.  What are the steps to add a toolchain for VC++ in Eclipse?  Has anyone tried it successfully?  If so, does the debugger still work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a toolchain implementation for VC++. The build plugin is called **[org.eclipse.cdt.msw.build](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.cdt/windows/?root=Tools_Project)**, and there is a set of debugger plugins called **org.eclipse.cdt.msw.debug.***. I think the build integration works, but the debugger integration still needs some work before it is usable.

Doug Schaefer on the CDT team has [blogged](http://cdtdoug.blogspot.com/2008/02/yearning-for-good-windows-toolchain.html) about this several times, and has been running the [Wascana](http://wascana.sourceforge.net/) project for some time to this end. Unfortunately, [he's no longer working actively on Wascana](http://cdtdoug.blogspot.com/2009/05/wascana-is-over.html).

If you wanted to put in some effort in bringing the VC++ toolchain and debug support closer to working condition, it would be **very** appreciated. I know that there are many people who would like to have that (myself included).

(The cdt-dev list can surely help you with further help and pointers.)

Comment: Sounds like a very useful project for someone.  I'm pretty well booked though.  I guess I'll use MinGW.  I don't want to be trapped using VisualStudio Express for IDE debugging.

Comment: If you want to use DLLs created by Visual Studio, MinGW will do fine. Static libs are more difficult, though.

Comment: I am VERY happy after switching to MinGW.  I like the fact that msys gives me a shell to do the old ./configure make.  I can now use most Unix libraries in Windows.  I built postgres from source in about two minutes.  I also built Boost and zlib and it seemed to go very smooth.  It is really like I'm using Unix, but end up with a Windows .exe that can be run natively.  Very cool!  Forget VC++, use MinGW!!!

Comment: org.eclipse.cdt.msw.build sounds like a cool feature, but how does one install it?

Comment: Not sure if it is available in the nightly build. You may have to check out the sources and build yourself.